# Is there a Notepad++ plugin or built-in feature that autocloses quotation marks?

Tags: notepad++

I have looked at TextFX, but to no avail.

Comment: Hard to imagine how it would work. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Like when you put one quotation mark it immediately puts another? or it intelligently determines where quote should go?

Comment: After typing the opening quotation mark, the closing quotation mark should automatically appear, just like braces are auto-closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xbrackets Lite plugin has a setting "Treat '' as brackets" which when enable does what you want (at least on my Notepad++ 5.5 installation).